# Separating submanifolds in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a submanifold. If M is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n\smallsetminus M$ has two components, then must the components be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Note that replacing "diffeomorphic" with "homeomorphic" the answer is negative. A a counterexample is obtained by taking as $M$ the Alexander horned sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus a point.

Comment: Your title does not seem to say anything directly about the question.  I suggested one possibility, but please feel free to change it.

Comment: For $n\neq 3$ the question is answered in http://www2.oberlin.edu/faculty/jcalcut/csi.pdf, which is  Connected Sum at Infinity and Cantrell-Stallings Hyperplane Unknotting, J. Calcut, H. King and L. Siebenmann), Rocky Mountain Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 42, 2012, 1803-1862.